# How do I link pure html form to controller in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have searched for quite some time on how to link pure html to mvc 4 controllers and came up empty. I am unsure of what I'm doing wrong, though I know there will be many errors in my code since I'm new to this.

I have a simple web page that I'm trying to link to a controller but I'm getting an error when ever I hit submit. I'm also using Bootstrap (not really used in this example but the links are there), but I'm sure that's not the source of this error and that it's server side. The error I'm getting is

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Button1_Click' is undefined
```

The HTML page is actually an aspx because I wanted to do easy conversions of small websites over from java.

Here is the example page (It's been edited many times with different variations of buttons to submit):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>arrggghh</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Page</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div class="content-form-blank2">


            <div>

                <table class="margin">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h4>Press button.</h4></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

           <form id="myform" action="Home" method="post">
                <input type="submit" onclick="Button1_Click" />
           </form>


                </div>


          </div>

            <div class="form-navigation-bottom">

            </div>


    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- script references -->
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my example controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using arrgg.code;

namespace arrgg.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        protected void Button1_Click()
        {           
            new arrggOut();
        }
    }
}
```

The error isn't as important as me understanding how to link pure html to the controller. Thanks in advance... if anyone has the required time to write a book about everything I'm doing wrong.

I will soon start using helpers and reading up more about asp.net and MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post from your form submission to the correct route e.g. /Home/DoSomething. Then, in your controller, provided the route has been established, you will be mapped through to the DoSomething method in your Home controller. Do not write it as Button1_Click(). When you click that button, it should simply submit the form with the appropriate URL as its action, unless you need to do something prior to submission e.g. client side validation. Then, the controller can handle it and do something meaningful with it, described by the method name.

View:

```
<form id="myform" action="/Home/DoSomething" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
namespace arrgg.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            // Or whatever you require here...
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Further info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-an-action-cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought I was doing something wrong when I typed the name of the controller then action though I remember c# resolving controller names such as 'name%'. I kept changing it because of the different errors I was getting due to my pc acting up and needing a reset.

Answer (score 1):

Button1_Click is JavaScript event. Call controller action from this event.
 Add this text to the bottom of the html:

```
<script>
    function Button1_Click() {
        $.post('/Home/Button1_Click', {}, function(res) {
        });
    }
</script>
```

To avoid JavaScript change html. Instead of:

```
       <form id="myform" action="Home" method="post">
            <input type="submit" onclick="Button1_Click" />
       </form>
```

Write:

```
       <form id="myform" action="/Home/Button1_Click" method="post">
            <input type="submit" />
       </form>
```

And change controller action. It must be public and return ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Button1_Click()
    {           
        return RedirectToAction("/Home/Index");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to do it with just html and my controller

Comment: Added code how call controller action without javascript

Comment: Getting odd 404 errors.. sigh, occasionally I have trouble with my IDEs have to reset and will update in a bit.

Comment: hm. old mvc does not support '~' in paths. update answer

Comment: It shouldn't be Button1_Click as the name of the controller method. It should be something meaningful for the action required.

Comment: the '~' wasn't the source of the 404 error, I never used it but thank you. I needed to reset this computer, which doesn't happen as often as it should. I wish I could mark this as correct but Mano's answer was the correct answer and he answered first, which would have worked if I had reset earlier (I probably wouldn't have had to ask this question had I done that :( ... ). I got the 404 error using his suggestions first and realized it was my computer after getting it a second time.