# How do I connect a form in .cshtml to a controller in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

**Problem:**
I'm building a full stack web application in C#, but I cannot get the form data from the Razor Pages into the controller!

This is in my input form:

```
@model OrderProcessingApplication.Model.Order
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Ordering Application";
}

<div class="text-center">
<h1 class="display-4">Shirt Ordering Application</h1>
<p>Process an order</p>
p>Process an order</p>
<form id="submitOrderForm" action="ProcessNewOrder" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <!--Name-->
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required><br><br>

        <!--address-->
        <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Notice the "action of the form is "ProcessNewOrder" **

This is my controller:

```
    public class processOrder : ControllerBase
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public String ProcessNewOrder(Order order)
    {
        return "order received";
    }
}
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How would I change this so that the submission of this form on a post request submits a new Order model to the controller?

**What I have already tried:**

1. [This example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-an-action-cs) is not helpful because it says I should use *ProcessOrder : Controller* but it doesn't seem to work. ControllerBase is the only one available. When I try using the exact same imports, it reads 'Controller is a namespace but is used as a type'.
2. [This second example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/web-development-full-stack-csharp-with-blazor) is not helpful because:
   (1) The sample code doesn't exist anymore
   (2) It is over 11 years old
   (3) It doesn't actually even show the form that's being used (not helpful)
3. **These two seem like the closest,** but [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1) and also [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408427/how-do-i-link-pure-html-form-to-controller-in-c-sharp) both still instructs me to use the : Controller option.

I'm going to continue to troubleshoot this but this seems like a relatively routine thing to do and I'm surprised nobody has clear documentation on it yet.

**For those wondering:** This is my order model:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace OrderProcessingApplication.Model
  {
      public class Order : Entity
      {
    
    public Order(Guid id, DateTime date, string customerName, string customerAddress, string 
       customerPhone, COLOR color, Size size, double price, int quantity, double totalCost, Status 
         status, string notes)
    {

        DateTime Date = date;
        string CustomerName = customerName;
        string CustomerAddress = customerAddress;
        string CustomerPhone = customerPhone;
        COLOR Color = color;
        Size Size = size;
        double Price = price;
        int Quantity = quantity;
        Status Status = status;
        double TotalCost = totalCost;
        string Notes = notes;

    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
    string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    COLOR Color { get; set; }
    Size size { get; set; }
    double price { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    Status Status { get; set; }
    double TotalCost { get; set; }
    string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

> The error I get is always the same:
>
> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
> address: https://localhost:44367/ProcessNewOrder HTTP ERROR 404

I have tried following one of the closer examples as follows:

```
namespace OrderProcessingApplication.Controller
{
    [Route("ProcessNewOrder")]
    [ApiController]
    public class processOrder : ControllerBase
    { 
        [HttpPost]
        public String ProcessNewOrder([FromBody] Order order)
        {
            return "order received";
        }
    }
}
```

Again, it turns up the same 404 error.

Comment: `Route("/....")` or it's a relative path... Though I would actually fix it with form tag helpers.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Doesn't work. Exact same result.

Comment: I think MVC will only bind constructors of c#9 record types. Otherwise you'll need settable properties and a default constructor.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-form-tag-helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `action="ProcessNewOrder"` to `action="/ProcessNewOrder"`.Here is a demo:

View:

```
<form id="submitOrderForm" action="/ProcessNewOrder" method="post">
   

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[Route("ProcessNewOrder")]
    [ApiController]
    public class processOrder : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public String ProcessNewOrder()
        {
            return "order received";
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you use controllers in razor page app,you need to add endpoint in startup.cs like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: I literally have this exact same code and it isn't working.

Comment: So you mean you use the same code,and you will go to https://localhost:44367/ProcessNewOrder,but you get 404.You use controllers in razor pages app,right?

Comment: The answer is that startup.cs didn't have the the correct endpoints in it. I don't know how that got switched up but that was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to submit a form, or data for that matter. You can send it through a request (via form submission or via ajax) or through an open socket.

Some of those may be a little more advanced than the situation we are looking at though.

When you are considering submitting a form via form submission, as in you click the submit button and it posts, then a model binder is used behind the scenes.

First, the route handler kicks in, and uses reflection to take the url path and map it to a controller action in order to invoke that method and call it. Once that happens, the values of the submitted form are injected into the parameters.

When using a classical form submission (ajax is different), the name of the parameter in the action result does not matter. However, the property names do. When you have a class defined as the parameter, it is essentially an object with properties. The model binder will attempt to fill any property values in that object, with values from the form, by matching the `name=""` as the property name, and then taking that value and assigning it to the property value.

Now, the model is considered to be populated in the action result by the model binder. Then you can handle the response. Usually a `return redirectToAction('ReturnViewName');` is used to facilitate the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, also known as the PRG pattern. In your case you are just returning a string, which will probably just write that to the screen of the browser once its finished.